# Url's not working after i remove the "$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] "from $path-open cart 2

Tags: php, css, opencart

When i'm migrated my website from live server to localhost i change in my config file,below i show you what changes then my menu link not working get object not found page..
Before:

```
$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

After:

```
$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "", ""));
```

In my footer menu "Stores" menu item when i click on that get blank page,

```
<li><a href="<?php echo MAIN_URL;?>stores">Stores</a></li>
```

I didn't get what changes i will do...please help me.

I'm changed code to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] after that get error

> Warning: require_once(/ecompusell/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecompusell\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/ecompusell/system/startup.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecompusell\index.php on line 17

Below is my config.php..

```
$root = '';
$url = 'http://localhost/ecompusell/';

$projectpath = '';

$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "", ""));
$url2= $url.$path;
$rootfolder = $path;
```

Comment: Why you remove this ?

Comment: Because the banner and product images not show.

Comment: than issue with image path not change the main path.

Comment: but still error in menu ?why?

Comment: Than post more code

Comment: http://localhost/ecompusell/stores it shows object not found.

Comment: i will post my config file please check

Answer (score 2):

It's because in the two `str_replace` that you changed, you replace an empty string !
Also, try to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead of `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` for HTML links.
So your code should be:

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/";
```

and it should work.

Have a nice day

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136040/discussion-on-answer-by-ad5001-gameur-codeur-autre-urls-not-working-after-i).